# image view loads old image from url even when its updated

Tags: ios, caching, sdwebimage

i am using SDWebimageView to load image from imageview , when user update image it doesn't reflect on image view and load old image

```
if let image = SessionManager.shared.getUser()?.profilePic {
            profileImg.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: Constant.assetUrl+image), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "user (6)-1"),options : .refreshCached)
        }else{
            profileImg.image = UIImage(named: "user (6)-1")
        }
```